# how to group_concat on concatenated results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem in `group_concat()` of `concatenated` results.

here is what i'm doing to get `concat()` result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e95b4/6

**here is my Query:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(from_day,' ',from_month,' ',from_date,' ',from_year,' ',from_time) startTime,
CONCAT(to_day,' ',to_month,' ',to_date,' ',to_year,' ',to_time) endTime 
FROM availability WHERE user_id = 148
```

**my desired output:**

startTime.'   '.endTime.' '.startTime.'  '.endTime........

**or**

```
FROM Fri Oct 27 2017 12:00:00 To Fri Oct 27 2017 12:00:00,FROM Fri Oct 27 2017 12:00:00 To Fri Oct 27 2017 12:00:00,FROM Fri Oct 27 2017 12:00:00 To Fri Oct 27 2017 12:00:00....
```

here is my demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e95b4/6

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('FROM ', from_day, ' ', from_month, ' ', from_date, ' ', from_year, ' ', from_time, 
                    ' TO ', to_day, ' ', to_month, ' ', to_date, ' ', to_year, ' ', to_time) as ranges 
FROM availability
WHERE user_id = 148;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e95b4/8) is a SQL Fiddle.